# How to manipulate elements created with jQuery using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to order some `div`'s with jQuery. They were created with jQuery from a Google Sheet using JSON.

Why does the content disappear when I run the function to order the `div`s? Is it because the content was originally created with jQuery?

HTML

```
Sort by

<select id="myselect">
  <option value="distance">Distance</option>
  <option value="atoz">A to Z</option>
</select>

<div id="list"></div>
```

jQuery

```
// Add content from Google Sheet

$.getJSON('http://cors.io/?u=https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1pksFEATRRWfOU27kylZ1WLBJIC-pMVxKk9YlCcDG0Kk/od6/public/values?alt=json', function(data) {
  $.each(data.feed.entry, function(i, v) {
    var url = v.gsx$url.$t;
    var shortUrl = url.replace('http://', '');
    var data = $('<div class="listing" data-listing-name="' + v.gsx$name.$t + '" data-listing-distance="' + v.gsx$distance.$t + '">').append('<img src="' + v.gsx$image.$t + '" id="image"/><h4 id="bandb">' + v.gsx$name.$t + '</h4><a href="' + v.gsx$url.$t + '" id="link">' + shortUrl + '</a><p id="description">' + v.gsx$description.$t + '</p>');
    $('#list').append(data);
  });

});

// Sort by distance

$(document).ready(function() {

  var distance = $(".listing");
  distance.sort(function(a, b) {
    return $(a).data("listing-distance") - $(b).data("listing-distance")
  });

  var atoz = $(".listing");
  atoz.sort(function(a, b) {
    return $(a).data("listing-name") - $(b).data("listing-name")
  });

  $("#myselect").on("change", function() {
    if ($("#myselect option:selected").text() == "A to Z") {
      $("#list").html(atoz);
    } else {
      $("#list").html(distance);
    }
  });

  $("#list").html(distance);
});
```

Comment: Try to use delegate() for binding function to your #myselect

Comment: There's really no guarantee that the asynchronous ajax call will be completed before `document.ready` fires, so you won't know it the elements are there are not. The sorting should be done in the success callback of the ajax call

Comment: In fact, the reason the elements disappear, is probably because the elements aren't there at all when you do the sorting, and `distance` and `atoz` are empty, which means the entire sorting should happen in the event handler.

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
$("#list").html(distance);
```

as you last statement. If you check [JQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/html/) what this mean you would know that this statemtnt expect html as input and will override entire content of element. So once agina what you are doing:

1. Add element to container with id list
2. Do some ordering code. (Which really only sort elements within your array, and do not reorder them inside container.
3. Then you do code mentioned above - which override content of list container with string representation od object distance, but string representation of object distance is not the same as html - that exactly the reason why everything disappeared.

You can solve this issue by using Something like this:

```
distance.each(function(i, e) {
    $("#list").append(e);
});
```

This will take every element and put it in the end of container with id "list" essentially re-ordering them.

P.S.: As pointed in comment - you should alter your code to make sure it is executed after you loaded data as document.ready event might fired earlier - so mo re-ordering code into event handling function.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to remove `$("#list").html(distance);`. I am new to coding and I'm not sure what event handling function is. It is still vanishing.
http://jsfiddle.net/5rh2am42/7/